# What fedora 15 should I download?

Tags: fedora, nvidia

I would like to get Fedora 15, but I also need `kmod-nvidia-PAE` drivers. So, which iso exactly should download to make the `kmod-nvidia` work when I will download it by RPM Fusion? (Like the right kernel, not one that `kmod-nvidia` isn't made for.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind some extra aditional dependencies you might want to take a look at `akmod-nvidia` (also found on the rpmfusion repository).

`akmod-nvidia` will build a suitable driver for you kernel, regardless of kernel version. This means less waiting for a new driver when the kernel version is updated. I really recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

If it has to be kmod-nvidia-PAE then it sounds like you'll need the 32 bit version.

However, RPM Fusion should have 64 bit nvidia drivers as well - just install kmod-nvidia and it should pick the right one for your kernel, regardless of whether you install Fedora 32 or 64 bit.